# How can I record the screen as well as audio on Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, screen, screencast, desktop-recording, sound-recorder

That is for creating a video tutorial. I want the screen and my voice.
I have tried many recorder, but that only record the screen and internal video.

Answer (score 18):

A simple one is **simplescreenrecorder** which can be found in the 18.04 repo. Install it with

```
sudo apt install simplescreenrecorder
```

start it > Continue > choose size of screen to record > tick the box for audio. For Backend choose pulseaudio. For source choose `built in audio analogue stereo` which would record the mic instead of the internal audio > choose save location and the default codec parameters should be ok

[image]

Answer (score 11):

There is an application in the Official Ubuntu Software Repository callled Kazam, which works great. It will record internal sound, external sound, and the screen. It has pretty good video quality, as well. It can be installed with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install kazam
```

Comment: There is currently a bug with this application where it doesn't save your preferences, especially with speaker & mic volumes.

Comment: @LostCrotchet I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and preferences are getting saved here.

Answer (score 6):

There are many many applications with which you can do that, The best one that I've used obs, You can install it by

```
sudo apt install obs-studio
```

As previously suggested you can also use kazam

```
sudo apt install kazam
```

Or if you don't want to install any application, you can use the already available `ffmpeg` command, the following should work for you:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s "Your screen resolution" -i :0.0 -f alsa -i default output.mkv
```

For the last one, I am assuming you're using `alsa`!

Comment: I was going to mention OBSProject - I wasn't aware it is in the repositories, though!

Answer (score 4):

Since ubuntu 21.04, it seems `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R` will record the screen.
Quote [from](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html):

> Make a screencast
> You can make a video recording of what is happening
> on your screen:
> Press `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R` to start recording what is on your screen.
> A red circle is displayed in the top right corner of the screen when
> the recording is in progress.
> Once you have finished, press `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R` again to stop the
> recording.
> The video is automatically saved in your Videos folder in your home
> folder, with a file name that starts with Screencast and includes the
> date and time it was taken.
>
> If you do not have a Videos folder, the videos will be saved in your
> home folder instead

Comment: this works great but I'm unable to record audio from my usb microphone that's plugged in and detected.

Comment: @pseudozach check [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ScreenCasts)

Comment: thanks I ended up using simplescreenrecorder, did the job ok after installing h264 plugins.

Comment: This records only 30 seconds.

Comment: This phrase seems false in Ubuntu 22.04 - _Once you have finished, press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R again to stop the recording._ Does not work. Agree with @pseudozach, This app does not record audio but video only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [recordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php). It has the option to capture audio from your microphone. To install it run the following command in Terminal

```
sudo apt install gtk-recordmydesktop
```

Open recordMyDesktop and just check the box next to '*Sound Quality*' before starting recording.

[image]

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, `gtk-recordmydesktop` is no more in the repositories (the main CLI `recordmydesktop` package still is). However, it is possible to install `gtk-recordmydesktop` package from 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

What about the **peek** app ?

Have been long using it and have to admit have no trouble whereas had with Kazam.

The main problem is that cannot record audio.

Hope anyone may help me out in order to can do so !!

Comment: If you have a question, you need to ask a new question, referring back to this question, using the URL, if you feel that they are related. You can't post questions in the answer section, nor append a supplementary question to an answer.